# How to know which process instance a message was delivered to?

Tags: activiti, bpmn, camunda

How can I have the ProcessInstanceId of the process instance(s) that a sent message has been delivered to?

I'm sending the message through REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include some **unique identifier** just known by the sender in your message as a **process variable** (see e.g. [Camunda BPM REST API 'message' endpoint](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#message)). Such a process variable is then held by your targeted process instance just after **really** having received the message.

So, after having sent the message, you can then as a second step query for the receiving process instance (see e.g. [Camunda BPM REST API 'get-instances' endpoint](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#process-instance-get-instances)) which holds the variable with the expected identifier.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK the only way to do this is if you include the source execution or process id in the message. If you´re sending the message through the the runtime services API, then your code should look something like this:

```
String myPid = delegateExecution.getProcessInstanceId();
Map vars = new HashMap();
vars.put('senderProcessInstanceId',myPid);

delegateExecution
    .getEngineServices()
    .getRuntimeService()
    .messageEventReceived("someMessage",targetExecution,vars);
```

After executing this code, the receiving process can then retrieve the content of the process var "senderProcessInstanceId" in order to know who was the sender.

If you´re using the REST API, then you´d use

```
PUT runtime/executions/{executionId}
```

Using a JSON body like that:

```
{
    "action":"messageEventReceived",
    "messageName":"myMessage"
    "variables": [ {"name": "senderProcessInstanceId", "value":"xxxxx"}  ]
 }
```

Comment: How can I include process id in the message? First of all, process id is something that is generated at run time, while message is defined at design time! Secondly, if I know the process id to include it in the message, then it won't be a matter of finding it! BTW, I'm using REST API. Thanks for mentioning it, now I included it in the stem.

Comment: I think what Philippe Sevestre wanted to suggest is that you include some unique identifier just known by the sender in your message as a processVariable (http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#message). Such a processVariable is then held by your targeted process instance after *really* having received the message. After having sent the message, you can then as a second step query for the process instance (http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#process-instance-get-instances) which holds the variable with the expected identifier.

Comment: My answer  was based on the assumption the the sender party is using Activiti´s API in order to send the message.

Comment: @MartinSchimak Your suggestion would work. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to flag it. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre But I don't know which type of process (ProcessDefinition) will be getting the message! Let alone the execution!

Comment: You don´t need to know that.

You´d  use the API in order to query for executions that are waiting on a given message.  Then you would have its execution and can use it in order to send the message. If this is done inside a process (not always true), then you´d also have the  sender process instance id.